Pandas read XML file with designated data type
My code:
df = pd.read_xml(
    path_or_buffer=PATH,
    xpath="//Data",
    compression="gzip"
)

I'm using Pandas read_xml() function to read xml.gz format data. I'm using Pandas 1.3.2 version. When I tried to read the data, Pandas read data wrongly.
The data looks like as below. Both colA and colB should be a string.
1st data file:
<Data>
 <colA>abc</colA>
 <colB>168E3</colB>
</Data>
<Data>
 <colA>def</colA>
</Data>

2nd data file:
<Data>
 <colA>ghi</colA>
 <colB>23456</colB>
</Data>
<Data>
 <colA>jkl</colA>
</Data>

When I use read_xml() function, it looks like below:
1st dataframe:
colA: abc, def
colB: 168000.0, None

2nd dataframe:
colA: ghi, jkl
colB: 23456.0, None

I want to read the data in string format but there is no dtype argument in pandas 1.3.2. I want to know:

How can I read the data with designated data type?
When there is missing data in a column, Pandas will assign the float type to that column. How to avoid it, or is there any setting to configure the data type of column with missing value when data is read?

Please note that I can only this Pandas version and can't update it.

Applying a simple xslt transformation to force string type on every value could work (I don't have pandas 1.3.2 to test but works on pandas 2.x). It does not seem possible to obtain a canonical answer given the version contraint. An alternative could be to parse xml doc with lxml and manually populate the dataframe.
The transformation concatenates a non number character that is later removed
XSLT
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="'|'"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xml_ ="""\
<root>
<Data>
 <colA>abc</colA>
 <colB>168E3</colB>
</Data>
<Data>
 <colA>def</colA>
</Data>
</root>"""

file = StringIO(xml_)

df = pd.read_xml(xml_, stylesheet="/home/lmc/tmp/test.xslt" )
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:-1]))

Result
  colA   colB
0  abc  168E3
1  def   None

Original result
   colA    colB
0  abc|  168E3|
1  def|    None


If you're able to install other libraries, you can read the XML file as a dict with xmltodict, then use that to create the pandas dataframe.
import gzip
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd

def read_xml_as_dict(gzip_path):
    with gzip.open(gzip_path, "r") as f:
        xml = f.read()
    return xmltodict.parse(xml)

data = read_xml_as_dict(PATH)
df = pd.DataFrame(data["root"]["Data"])

If you cannot install xmltodict, you can parse it using xml.etree.ElementTree in a similar way:
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

def read_xml_as_dict(gzip_path):
    with gzip.open(gzip_path, "r") as f:
        xml = f.read()

    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    data_list = []

    for item in root.findall("Data"):
        data_dict = {}
        for child in item:
            data_dict[child.tag] = child.text
        data_list.append(data_dict)

    return data_list

data = read_xml_as_dict(PATH)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Both will print:
  colA   colB
0  abc  168E3
1  def    NaN


Columns will have dtype object:
df.info()

 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   colA    2 non-null      object
 1   colB    1 non-null      object


Define the dtype of the columns in pandas:
(NaN will read as class 'NoneType', but you can use astype() later
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xml_ ="""\
<root>
<Data>
 <colA>abc</colA>
 <colB>168E3</colB>
</Data>
<Data>
 <colA>def</colA>
</Data>
</root>"""

file = StringIO(xml_)

df = pd.read_xml(file, xpath=".//Data", dtype={'colA': str, 'colB': str})
print(df.astype(str).applymap(type))


Output:
            colA           colB
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>


Thanks for your answer, but there is no dtype argument for read_xml() in pandas==1.3.2.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.2/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html

But the last statement with astyp() should work anyway.

It works, but as the data is parsed wrongly at the beginning (eg 168E3 -> 168000.0), even astype() works, it will become a 168000.0 string.

Change to the newer version of pandas, if possible. I use Version: 2.0.3.

Thanks for your comment, but I can't upgrade to newer version. I'm trying to find if there is any solution that can config the default data type / disable it.
